# AaptProcess in project Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, aapt, aapt2

Currently im my notebook I'm having trouble starting the development of a simple application using Flutter in Android Studio 3.2.
When I run I get errors in the console:

[Erro Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ano4.png)

I solved this problem by adding: android.enableAapt2 = false in the gradle.properties file.
I ran the application around again and everything worked perfectly.
I hope I can be useful.

Comment: Don't know if they are related: But I was having issues after upgrading the Kotlin-Version in combination with the Android Gradle plugin and Gradle itself (the wrapper). Reverted to the former version and it worked, but will try your "solution", ASAP.

Comment: What is your system? Do you have an anti-virus?

Comment: Windows 10. No anti-virus installed in my machine.